# Random crashes in app developed with Titanum Mobile for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, titanium, titanium-mobile

I've developed an iPhone app using the [Titanum Mobile from Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/), and I've been experiencing crashes and memory leaks for some time now... Thankfully the crashes only happened rarely, so that, despite them, my app was still usable.

However now that I have begun testing my app with iPhone 4S and iOS 5.0.1, the random crashes are now happening much more frequently for no apparent reason.

I have had reports that sometimes my app crashes repeatedly in a short amount of time and that sometime later it runs smoothly for over an hour and then crashes again.

Has anyone also experienced something similar?

Note: I am using the Titanium Mobile 1.7.5.

Comment: I had the same problem with 1.7.5, so I went back to 1.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

The reason : memory starvation. Although Titanium is supposed to take care of memory management for you, it doesn’t always work correctly. Most of the times, especially if your application is simple and doesn’t use many images and animations, the memory leaks Titanium generates over time will be small enough that you won’t even realise that your application is actually leaking. Problem is, when your application reaches a certain level of complexity, those leaks will become evident – in the form of sudden, unavoidable crashes.

to resolve you should try something from here - http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/116867/this-is-a-solution-to-your-memory-woes

Comment: I see, but do you think that there might be some problem that is related to the iPhone 4S? I mean, the same app that crashes rarely with the other iPhones (3G, 3GS and 4), is now crashing very very frequently with iPhone 4S.